# Ionic - Google Maps Full Screen

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps

I have a integrated a google maps in one of my ionic application pages and it is working fine on all browsers, and mobile platform. I used this one;

```
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: {lat: -33, lng: 151},
    zoomControl: false,
    fullscreenControl: true
  });
}
```

but it was not working on almost most of the platforms.

This is my .html

```
<ion-header *ngIf="FullScreen">
    <ion-navbar class="navbar">
        <ion-grid no-padding>
            <ion-row align-items-center class="navbarSection">
                <ion-col col-4 class="menuSection">
                    <button tappable ion-button menuToggle>
                        <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
                        <div>
                            Menu
                        </div>
                    </button>
                </ion-col>
                <ion-col col-4 class="titleSection">
                    <ion-title>
                        <h5>Customers</h5>
                    </ion-title>
                </ion-col>
                <ion-col col-4 class="buttonsSection">
                    <ion-buttons>
                        <button ion-button icon-left (click)="CreateCustomer()">
                            <ion-icon name="contact"></ion-icon>
                            New Customer
                        </button>
                    </ion-buttons>
                </ion-col>
            </ion-row>
            <ion-row align-items-center>

            </ion-row>
        </ion-grid>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content class="backcolor-pagegray">    
    <div [hidden]="!MapView" #map id="map"></div>
</ion-content>
```

I tried to do this one https://www.doogal.co.uk/FullScreen.php
but I had typescript errors.
What is the best way to achieve that?

Comment: Can you put your html code or a picture about what you want exactly?

Comment: I have a map in one of the pages that takes around 80% screen except the header menu section. I want something similar to this.https://www.doogal.co.uk/FullScreen.php. but had some issues with the typescript(was getting HTMLDivElement  errrors).

I can put custom buttons on google maps and show hide elements on my page(the header) but could not do that either. If you can help me with that I'll be thankful

Comment: I updated the html

Comment: did u find any solution?

Comment: I created new ionic page with only the map. I set height and width to 100%. Basically on mobile it looks like full screen. But on browser you still see your tabs above. I added a custom button on the Map and when you click on it I redirect to the ionic page and pass the location as data.